# Nickname all members in a discord server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a script that can nickname all the people on a discord server I would like it to rename all the members and not only the active ones for the moment I have this

```
module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args, config) => {
msg.delete();
const guild = client.guilds.get("888868333498290176");
    if(!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")) return console.log('Cette commande a besoin de permissions')
    await msg.guild.members.cache;
    let members = msg.guild.id

    if (args.join(" ").length > 32) return msg.reply('Le nom ne peut pas dépasser 32 caractères.')
    console.log('Modifier le surnom de ' + members.length + ' member(s), attendez un moment.')
    for(let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {

        await members[i].setNickname(args.join(" "))
       
    }

    console.log('  [+] Le surnom de tout le monde sur le serveur a été changé !'.green)

}
```

and this error

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\discord\1140\commands\nickall.js:12
        await members[i].setNickname(args.join(" "))
                         ^

TypeError: members[i].setNickname is not a function
```

Comment: `members` is the guild id. It's not an array of members. It's not even an array at all, it's a string.

Comment: Also `msg.guild.members.cache` does not return a promise nor does it have any side effects, why are you awaiting it?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use **`forEach()`** and change nicknames for all members in the guild. Example:

```js
try {
   message.guild.members.forEach((member) => {
      member.setNickname("nickname")
   })
} catch (error) {
   console.error(error)
   return message.channel.send(`Error changing nicknames: \`${error}\``)
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but it dont rename all people